# how to use the set nickname article?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make my discord bot change the nickname of a user when they send `!name Travis_c`

here is my code

```js
case 'name':
    message.author.setNickname(args[1], 'Account setup')
break;
```

I think I'm doing it right, but it keeps saying `.setnickname is not a function.` if I'm not using it right, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `.setNickname()` on the `User` which won't work since only `GuildMember` has the `nickname` property and the `setNickname()` method

```js
case 'name':
  message.member.setNickname(args[1], 'Account setup')
break;
```